# How to make Collision

Tags: java, collision, pacman

I am making Pac-Man. I have, for now, have one player controlled PacMan and one player controlled ghost. They both extend the same abstract class. I am having trouble figuring out a way to check to see if they are colliding. This is the abstract class
`

```
package org.entity.mobs;

import java.awt.Point;
import org.Constants;
import org.entity.Entity;

public abstract class Mob extends Entity {

    private Point destination;
    protected int nextDirection = 4;
    protected int direction;
    protected int tempX;

    public Mob(int x, int y) {
        super(x, y);
        destination = new Point();
    }

    public void update() {
        if (Constants.walls[destination.y][destination.x] != 1) {
            switch (direction) {
                case 1:
                    y -= 2;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    y += 2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    x -= 2;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    x += 2;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (onGrid()) {
            direction = nextDirection;
        }
    }

    public void setNextDirection(int key) {
        switch (key) {
            case Constants.PACMAN_UP:
                this.nextDirection = 1;
                break;
            case Constants.PACMAN_DOWN:
                this.nextDirection = 2;
                break;
            case Constants.PACMAN_LEFT:
                this.nextDirection = 3;
                break;
            case Constants.PACMAN_RIGHT:
                this.nextDirection = 4;
                break;
        }
    }

    public Point getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

    public void setDestination() {
        Point point = new Point();
        switch (direction) {
            case 1: // up
                point.setLocation(x / 20, ((y - 1) / 20));
                if (x % 20 <= 4 || x % 20 >= 16) {
                    tempX = (x + 5) / 20;
                } else {
                    tempX = x;
                }
                break;
            case 2: // down
                point.setLocation(x / 20, (y / 20) + 1);
                if (x % 20 <= 4 || x % 20 >= 16) {
                    tempX = (x + 5) / 20;
                } else {
                    tempX = x;
                }
                break;
            case 3: // left
                point.setLocation(((x - 1) / 20), y / 20);
                if (x % 20 <= 4 || x % 20 >= 16) {
                    tempX = (x + 5) / 20;
                } else {
                    tempX = x;
                }
                break;
            case 4: // right
                point.setLocation((x / 20) + 1, y / 20);
                if (x % 20 <= 4 || x % 20 >= 16) {
                    tempX = (x + 5) / 20;
                } else {
                    tempX = x;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        destination.setLocation(point);
    }

    public boolean onGrid() {
        return (x % 20 == 0) && (y % 20 == 0);
    }
}
```

`
And here is where I was going to put the collide method

```
    package org;

import org.entity.tiles.Wall;
import org.entity.tiles.Pellet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.entity.Entity;
import org.entity.mobs.Mob;

public class Grid {

    private Entity[][] grid = new Entity[31][28];
    private ArrayList<Mob> entities = new ArrayList<>();

    public Grid() {
        // Fills grid
        for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < grid[0].length; col++) {
                switch (Constants.walls[row][col]) {
                    case 0:
                        grid[row][col] = new Pellet(col, row);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        grid[row][col] = new Wall(col, row);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        // TODO middle
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        grid[row][col] = new Pellet(col, row, true);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        // TODO: possibly add more
    }

    public void update() {
        // move entities in units that can evenly go into 20 (1,2,4,5,10,20)
        for (Mob mob : entities) {
            mob.setDestination();
            mob.update();
        }
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        // Draw Maze
        g.drawImage(ImageLibrary.MAZE.getImage(), 0, 0, null);

        // draws Tiles
        for (Entity[] row : grid) {
            for (Entity tile : row) {
                if (tile != null) {
                    tile.draw(g);
                }
            }
        }

        // draws mobs
        for (Entity mob : entities) {
            mob.draw(g);
        }
    }

    public void add(Mob entity) {
        entities.add(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Checkout this: http://www.edu4java.com/en/game/game6.html

Comment: You could create a getBounds() method for both sprites and check if they intersect. Pro tip: Just because your sprite is not a rectangle doesn't mean the collision detection can't be a rectangle

Answer (score 0):

Create a java.awt.Rectangle in the Entity class. The coordinates of the rectangle represent the bounding box for the collision detection to occur. In your entity update, update the position of the rectangle.

In your Grid class, create a method chrckCollisions and iterate through the entity array and check if each entity is colliding with another entity. (Search "handshake problem", this is a rudemenetary approach, but you can always optimize it.) There is a intersects(Rectangle) method within the rectangle that you should use.

Have a method in you Entity class that is "public abstract void onCollision(Entity other)". Here you specify for each subclass what to do on collision with another entity. For example, if we are in the ghost subclass, check if we are colliding with pacman and then perform certain actions.

This method is called when two Entities are found to be colliding. Hope this helps.